# Optional stopping theorem: different versions

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

$(X_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sub-martingale, $R_1,R_2$ two stopping times such that $R_1 \leq R_2$.

The optional stopping theorem which I know is the following (from probability theory, independence, interchangeability, martingales: theorem 5 page 248, other reference Shiryaev probability 2: theorem 1 page 119):

*Theorem $1$ : letting $X_{R_1}(w)=X_{R_1(w)}(w)1_{\{R_1<\infty\}}(w),$ if $X_{R_1},X_{R_2} \in L^1,$ $\liminf_k\int_{\{R_2>k\}}|X_k|dP=0$ then $E[X_{R_2}|\mathcal{F}_{R_1}] \geq X_{R_1}.$*

*Consider the following theorem from Shreve-Karatzas book:*

[image: 1]

*In the proof of theorem 3.22, he refers to theorem $9.3.5$ from a course in probability theory:*

[image: 2]
[image: 3]

*He refers to exercise $11$, which can be proved easily using theorem $1,$ as a counterexample to theorem $9.3.5$ (not true for all cases):*

[image: 4]

*What's the difference between theorem $1$ and theorem $9.3.5$ ? In theorem $3.22,$ is it necessary to define $X_{\infty}$ as the almost sure limit ? What are the weakest conditions to obtain $E[X_{R_2}|\mathcal{F}_{R_1}] \geq X_{R_1}$ ?*

Comment: Could you please include full references to the books/papers you are quoting from?

Comment: References added

Comment: @Kurt.W.X, Does still interesting in this question right now?

Comment: Sure, it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I am charmed to see people are still using Chung's book.  By the the index that Chung uses, $N_{\infty}$ , he means that the supermartingale is a supermartingale up to and in including $\infty$.  If you were to say this about martingales you would mean that there was a limit, $X_{\infty}$, and the $E(X_{\infty}|F_n ) = X_n$, closeable may be the term.  This is strong, the  martingale is uniformly integrable,  and  the conditions of your  first theorem are guaranteed.$$$$
A counterexample to keep in mind is recurrent random walk,  where you might take $\beta = inf \lbrace n>5: S_n = 0 \rbrace $, in which case $S_5, S_{\beta}$ is clearly not a martingale

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $X=\{X_n,\mathscr{F}_n; n\in N_+ \}$ is a sub-martingale, $R_1,R_2$
are two  stopping times such that $R_1\le R_2$. Denote
\begin{equation*}
    \mathsf{E}[X_{R_2}|\mathscr{F}_{R_1}]\ge X_{R_1}. \tag{1}
\end{equation*}

1. *What's the difference between theorem 1 and theorem 9.3.5*:

Both theorem 1 and theorm 9.3.5 give the conditions of (1) holds, but theorem 1 is for the a **fixed** $R_2$, theorem 9.3.5 give the sufficient conditions of (1) holds for **arbitrary** stopping time $R_2(\ge)R_1$.

2. *Is it necessary to define $X_\infty$ as the almost sure limit?*

To get the conclusion of therem 9.3.5, usually, suppose that the (sub/super-)martingale
$X$ is right closed(cf. C. Dellacherie & P. Meyer, *Probabilities and Potential B*,
North-Holland, Amsterdam, 1982, p.5--, V.7--V.10). If $X$ is right closed, then
\begin{equation*}
    \lim_{n\to\infty}X_n=X_\infty, \quad
     X_\infty(\ge/\le)=\mathsf{E}[Y|\mathscr{F}_\infty] \qquad \text{a.s.}
\end{equation*}
and $X_\infty$ is the $\mathscr{F}_\infty$-measurable right closing element of $X$ also.

3. *What are the weakest conditions to obtain (1)*:

For fixed $R_2$, above mentioned Theorem 1 is the weakest conditions to obtain (1).
For arbitrary $R_2$, ``$X$ is right closed'' is the weakest conditions to obtain (1).